# Extensible code

Tags: plugins

I would like to write this piece of code in an extendible way.

```
$my_item = array(
'post_title' => $item->get_title(),
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_excerpt' => $item->get_description(),
'post_type' => 'post'
);
```

If I use this in a plugin I would like to be able to create another plugin that can change that array and give different values or parameters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a filter:

```
$my_item = apply_filters( 
    'plugin_name_item_args',
    array(
        'post_title'   => $item->get_title(),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_excerpt' => $item->get_description(),
        'post_type'    => 'post'
    ),
    $item # pass the $item object to the filter
);
```

A plugin can change these values now with:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_name_item_args', 'another_plugin_filter', 10, 2 );

function another_plugin_filter( $args, $item )
{
    $args['post_type'] = 'page';
    return $args
}
```

Comment: I get this error when using $args['post_title'] = $item->get_title(); in the plugin:  Fatal error: Call to a member function get_title() on a non-object.

Comment: So `$item` is not an object. Try `var_dump( $item );` to see what it is.

Comment: it is an object object(SimplePie_Item)[285]
  public 'feed' => 
    object(SimplePie)[288]

it works in the main plugin, but in the other plugin that contains the new array I get that error, so it appears that the $item object is not accessible from the new plugin that extends the original plugin.

Comment: Ah, I see. I made an update to my answer. You get the `$item` object now as second argument in you filter function.